# Setting error message on ExtJs 4.1 textareafield

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1

Please check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/webfriend13/yZHnm/23/). I have a simple textareafield. If user try to paste data into the textarea which contains more than 5 lines, I want to show error message by turning the border of the textareafield red & showing some message.

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
    Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
        height: 60,
        layout: 'anchor',
        minHeight: 60,
        width: 200,
        items: [{
            grow: true,
            anchor: '100%',
            flex: 1,
            enableKeyEvents: true,
            xtype: 'textareafield',
            id: 'txtFld',
            listeners: {
                keydown: function (txtArea, e, eOpts) {
                    //console.log(e.getKey());
                    if (e.keyCode == 13 && txtArea.value.split("\n").length >= 5) {
                        console.log('unable to stop :( ');
                        e.stopEvent();
                        return false;
                    }
                },
                paste: {
                    element: 'inputEl',
                    delay: 1,
                    fn: function (event, inputEl) {

                        if (event.type == "paste") {
                            if (inputEl.value.split("\n").length > 5) {

                                var enteredValues = inputEl.value.split("\n");
                                var modifiedText = inputEl.value.split("\n").slice(0, 5);
                                inputEl.value = modifiedText.join("\n");
                                // How to show Show error message stating some of the values are ignored ????


                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }]
    }).show();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`markInvalid`](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.TextArea-method-markInvalid) function on the textarea to achieve the behaviour which applies for regular validation and which basically is what you described as the desired behaviour.

```
Ext.getCmp('txtFld').markInvalid('Some content was removed');
```

I've updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yZHnm/27/) so you can have a look at it.

Comment: Thanks Matt for quick reply. The problem I am facing is even though i set the message using markInvalid(), system does not show error message for the first time. After the first time I am able to show the error message.  I am using same code as shared in the fiddle but not able to reproduce in the fiddle you shared.

Comment: I found the error as shown in this link : http://jsfiddle.net/webfriend13/yZHnm/29/   on line 34 instead of setting value like `Ext.getCmp('txtFld').setValue(modifiedText.join("\n"));`   I was using `inputEl.value = modifiedText.join("\n");`  and that is why system was not setting the red zig zag border for the first time.

Comment: Oh yes, I had changed that as well. Sorry for not mentioning it.